# disable click on Infinite Knob

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, bind, jquery-knob

I have this infinite knob that when the mouse is on hover the handler follows it.

http://jsfiddle.net/salvonostrato/FuVb2/

However, when the mouse is clicked the knob just stops working.

is there a way to disable the click event?

I have tried with :

```
$(".infinite").knob().click(function (event) { console.log("ok"); 
$(".infinite").knob().unbind( "click" );
//event.stopPropagation(); return false;
});
```

with no success..

Any suggestions?

Comment: You realize that clicking puts the slice where you click, and if you move your mouse out of the circle and back in it follows the mouse again.  I'd think this is the functionality you would want, otherwise you have to move your mouse out at just the right angle to get it to stay where want.

Comment: I just dont want the click to be recognised at all

Comment: It should stop after mouse out of that circle?

Comment: nope, if the mouse is clicked on the knob, the click event should not effect the knob. Right now if the mouse button is pressed the knob stops. I want to avoid that.